# How are these isomorphic $ K \otimes_{k_0} k \cong S^{-1} \left( R \otimes_{k_0} k \Big{/} P_0 \cdot (R \otimes_{k_0} k) \right)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, localization

Let $k_0$ be a field $k$ an algebraic closure of $k_0$. Let $R$ be a $k_0$ algebra and $P_0$ a prime ideal of $R$, $K$ is the fraction field of $R/P_0$. 
I am trying to understand how 
$$
K \otimes_{k_0} k \cong   S^{-1}  \left(   R \otimes_{k_0} k  \Big{/}   P_0 \cdot  (R \otimes_{k_0} k)    \right), $$
as $k_0$-algebras,
where
$$
S =   \{  z \otimes 1 +   P_0 \cdot  (R \otimes_{k_0} k):  z \in R  \backslash P_0  \}.
$$

Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: Can you at least write down what the map from $S^{-1}(\cdots)\to K\otimes_{k_0} k$ is? If you are struggling with this, here's a hint: start with a map $R\otimes_{k_0} k \to K\otimes_{k_0} k$ and then apply the 1st isomorphism theorem and the universal property of localization to get a map from $S^{-1}(\cdots)\to K\otimes_{k_0} k$.

Comment: Typo fixed. thank you

Comment: You can consider $S=R\setminus P_0$ and use that $S^{-1}(R\otimes k)\simeq (S^{-1}R)\otimes k$